# Automate the Page using Selenium VBA "https://wideo.co/text-to-speech/"

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, microsoft-edge

I want to download mp3 from the website "https://wideo.co/text-to-speech/"

But I unable to get the Elements from this website. Neither tag nor Name works.

```
Sub wideoAutomate()
    Dim obj As New WebDriver
    Dim ddl As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim ddl_1   As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim optionText, optionValue, voiceText, voiceValue As String
    
    
    obj.Start "edge", ""
    obj.Get "https://wideo.co/text-to-speech/"
    'obj.FindElementByTag("label").SendKeys ("I Went to College")
    obj.FindElementByName("label").SendKeys ("I Went to College")

end sub
```

I want complete automation for the above website. I unable to pick the Text area.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the driver has failed to locate the textarea is that it is placed under `<iframe>`, so you'll have to switch to that `<iframe>` first before you send keys. Otherwise, it will result in a **no such element** error. Also, I use CSS selector to locate the element so it is fast and precise. Try the following code:

```
Sub wideoAutomate()
    Dim obj As New WebDriver
    Dim ddl As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim ddl_1   As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim optionText, optionValue, voiceText, voiceValue As String
     
    obj.Start "edge", ""
    obj.Get "https://wideo.co/text-to-speech/"
    obj.SwitchToFrame obj.FindElementByTag("iframe")
    obj.Wait (2000)
    obj.FindElementByCss("#root > div > div.MuiFormControl-root.MuiTextField-root.jss4.MuiFormControl-marginNormal.MuiFormControl-fullWidth > div > textarea:nth-child(1)").SendKeys ("I Went to College")
    obj.Wait (5000)

End Sub
```

If it locates the textarea but fails to send keys, consider adding the first **Wait** time.